# Libraries for programming automata and Turing machines

Tags: automata-theory, turing-machines

What are the most useful libraries around for coding related to automata and Turing machines?

By useful I mean the number of functions and algorithms supported by it.

Comment: There is educational software for learning about automata and software for drawing automata, but I think that you're specifically asking about software that can utilize automata to help solve applied problems.

Comment: @MichaelWehar yep